# Multi-table SQL query - IN OPERATOR

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, I must us a query with the IN operator to come up with an answer. I am getting invalid character responses in Oracle. Thanks for any help!

Question - Find the book title for each book written by author number 18. Use the IN operator in your query.

What I seem to have so far:

```
SELECT TITLE

FROM BOOK

WHERE AUTHOR_NUM IN

{SELECT AUTHOR_NUM

FROM WROTE

WHERE AUTHOR_NUM = '18'};
```

The TITLE column is in the BOOK table, and the AUTHOR_NUM column is in the WROTE table. Sorry If I left out any info, any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: What columns do you have on `BOOK` and `WROTE`, I think you're correct in thinking you need to JOIN the two tables together then use the `IN` clause on the `WROTE` table

Answer (score 0):

Why are you quoting the 18? It's probably an integer column.  And since you are just going by the author number, I think you really want:

```
SELECT TITLE FROM BOOK WHERE AUTHOR_NUM IN (18)
```

That seems the simplest way to meet the requirements of the question.

Comment: The problem with that is that the AUTHOR_NUM is in a different table than the title. I think what needs to be done is to join the 2 tables, which is why I attempted it the way I did. If I run your code, i receive an error that says AUTHOR_NUM is an invalid identifier